# query all the earlier dates before a parameter sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, parameters

The follow procedure show only when the date I specified as a parameter, but not the earlier date.
I've specified `@date <= table2.date_column;` but this sentence only returns me the value that matches the date not earlier dates

```
create procedure pro
(
    @code int, @date datetime, @total smallint OUTPUT
)
as
begin
select
    table1.column1,
    table2.date_column
from
    table1
    inner join
    table2 on table1.column1 = table2.column2
where
    table1.column1 = @code
    and
    table2.date_column = @date
    and
    @date <= table2.date_column;

set @total = @@rowcount;
end
```

execute

```
declare @total smallint 
exec pro '1', '20140920', @total=@total output
select @total
```

Comment: you still have `table2.date_column = @date`. Take it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your `where` clause:

```
where table1.column1 = @code and
      table2.date_column = @date and
      @date <= table2.date_column;
```

You have two comparisons to `date_column`.  You only need one.  For equality:

```
where table1.column1 = @code and
      table2.date_column = @date;
```

For all dates before:

```
where table1.column1 = @code and
      table2.date_column <= @date;
```